# Autoplay audio only when the popup opens

Tags: html, audio

How do I do this? What would be the quickest, cleanest code to execute this task?

I input the  tag, but I'm pretty much lost after that

Answer (score 0):

add src file when popup open and remove it when popup close.
it is the simple way.